# onCancel conflict for Uploadify

Tags: javascript, uploadify

I am using Uploadify almost successfully. The images is uploaded but `onCancel` event gives me JavaScript error. It may be something related to conflicts. I am already using `$.noConflict();`
The error in console shows that the problem is in prototype. I tried what I knew in order to resolve this issue with no luck.

The error I can see in console: `TypeError: $(...) is null`. How can I fix this?

Comment: `<div class="cancel">
<a href="javascript:$('#file_upload').uploadify('cancel', 'SWFUpload_0_1')">X</a>
</div>`
Seems that this is the code generated by Uploadify. That '$' should be jQuery...or anyway another solution that does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to overwrite `itemTemplate` and to use there jQuery like:

```
'itemTemplate' : '<div id="${fileID}" class="uploadify-queue-item">\
                <div class="cancel">\
                    <a href="javascript:jQuery(\'#${instanceID}\').uploadify(\'cancel\', \'${fileID}\')\">X</a>\
                </div>\
                <input type="hidden" id="${fileID}" value="/uploads/${fileName}" name="file_upload_path[]" />\
                <span class="fileName">${fileName} (${fileSize})</span><span class="data"></span>\
                <div class="uploadify-progress">\
                    <div class="uploadify-progress-bar"><!--Progress Bar--></div>\
                </div>\
            </div>',
```